# how to import handsontable in angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, handsontable, angular6

I'm importing handsontable from the [official wrapper](https://github.com/handsontable/angular-handsontable)

import {HotTableModule} from '@handsontable/angular';

But the payload for this library grow of 2.29MB with all build optimisation just to add the default table.

Is there a beter way ?

Comment: Seems quite a reasonable size for a library, remember once you're importing the library, you're importing ALL the features as well. 2.29mb sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward I ran webpack-bundle-analyze and was scared when I saw that this lib took 30% of my whole bundle (without css). Moreover with preloadingStrategy I managed to download it in background so it doesn't block user interaction but in dev the module took 2-3s to load.